# A table's column of same cell of different spreadsheets

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have different spreadsheets (on the [following photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjHN4.png), from 1 to 25);
They have the same layout ( [Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65QjG.png) ).

I want to create a table with the `E7` cell of each spreadsheet (A table of every "Total").

I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeBjP.png) by extanding the formula...sounds good, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the first cell:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & ROW(1:1) & "'!E7")
```

And copy down.

Comment: ...or this. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following formula in the first 25 rows of your target sheet, it should do what you're trying to do:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,5,1,1,ROW()))
```

`ADDRESS` is formatting an address based on the parameters provided.

- 7 is the row
- 5 is the column (Column E)
- 1 says use an absolute reference $E$7
- 1 says us the A1 style address, not the R1C1 style.
- ROW() says use the sheet having the same name as the row where the column appears. So, in row 1, it will use sheet named "1". In row 8, it will use the sheet named "8"

`INDIRECT` says to get the value from the provided address.

If you need to put the list in a set of rows farther down the sheet, just use `ROW()-N` where N is one less than the number of rows from the where your list starts.  So, if your list of totals starts in row 3, use `ROW()-2`.